# How to nest Vue.nextTick when testing?

Tags: testing, vue.js, karma-runner

I'm trying to test what happens in my app on two consecutive ticks. This is what I have so far (the tests fail in the karma devtools, but fail in the command line):

```
import { mount } from 'avoriaz';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

describe('testing', function() {
  it('should do something', (done) => {
    const wrapper = mount(MyComponent, { store });
    wrapper.vm.changeData();
    Vue.nextTick(() => {
      expect(wrapper.vm.something).to.eql(somethingElse);
      wrapper.vm.changeData();
      Vue.nextTick(() => {
        expect(wrapper.vm.something2).to.eql(somethingElse2);
        done();
      });
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

I also tried using `then()` and `catch()`, but karma still thinks my failing tests are passing.

Should I only have one `done()` call? I'm not really sure what this callback is doing.

Comment: You should only have one `done()` call. It lets the test know it's finished. I'd expect that your test finishes after `expect(wrapper.vm.something).to.eql(somethingElse);`
but before `expect(wrapper.vm.something2).to.eql(somethingElse2);`

Comment: Ah, got it, so I should get rid of the second `done()`. I'd like to read more about this callback. Can you point me somewhere that explains this concept?

Comment: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/using-the-done-method-in-your-jasmine-driven-asynchronous-javascript-tests.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As indicated [here](https://wietse.loves.engineering/testing-promises-with-mocha-90df8b7d2e35), there is an even better solution, which prevents `Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.`:

```
it('should do something', (done) => {
  const wrapper = mount(MyComponent, { store });
  wrapper.vm.changeData();
  Vue.nextTick(() => {
    expect(wrapper.vm.something).to.eql(somethingElse);
    wrapper.vm.changeData();
    Vue.nextTick().then(() => {
      expect(wrapper.vm.something2).to.eql(somethingElse2);
    }).then(done, done);
  });
});
```

I'd like to also use the `async/await` version, but I wasn't able to get it to work.